# Equivalent of vcl DrawEdge in FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tbitmap

I'm trying to write an equivalent of FMX UI to replace the VCL.

What's the equivalent of `DrawEdge` in FMX cross-platform for these functions? (or nearest equivalent, if it cannot be the same)

```
var lRect: TRect;

DrawEdge(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle, lRect, EDGE_BUMP, BF_RECT or BF_MONO);       
DrawEdge(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle, lRect, EDGE_RAISED, BF_RECT);
DrawEdge(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle, lRect, EDGE_SUNKEN, BF_RECT);
DrawEdge(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle, lRect, EDGE_ETCHED, BF_RECT);
```

Thanks for any input.

Platform: Delphi 10.4 with FMX

Comment: [`DrawEdge()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawedge) is a Win32 API function, not a VCL function. There is no equivalent provided by FMX. You will just have to draw the edges yourself.

Comment: Has anyone come across an opensource fmx component that simulates this? so I don't have to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @PeterJones: Probably not, since FMX is about modern UIs and `DrawEdge` is about legacy 3D looks. In any case, it isn't a particularly complicated wheel.